# JSF/CDI session scoped bean corruption

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish, cdi

I'm afraid this question will be a bit vague but here goes...

We're noticing some very strange, occasional behaviour in our JEE7 web application. Sometimes a user's page will suddenly start displaying data from an entirely different user's session! So far I haven't been able to replicate this phenomenon nor find any indication of the problem in the logs, however it seems like one user's page starts displaying data that is stored in a @SessionScoped CDI bean that should belong to a different user's session.

Does this behaviour ring any bells for anyone? Any ideas about where to start looking, logging, or researching?

Our app is using Glassfish 4's SSO system. We're using JSF facelets, CDI backing beans, JPA entities. All reference implementations. All pretty close to latest versions.

We've also recently introduced a couple of simple SOAP based web services. Not closely linked to the areas we're having troubles with but maybe worth mentioning.

Any pointers or ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: A static field somewhere which should be non-static?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not to be able to yield an answer to your problem, but I am not allowed to comment on your question.

We are experiencing the exact behaviour you describe in our JEE7 web application on Glassfish 4 as well. In [my SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017334/weld-gf4-sessionscoped-sometimes-wrong-bean) I am describing how we tracked down the problem and found a way to bypass it. Did you meanwhile find a trace or maybe even a solution on this matter?